# ArangoDB: Join with nested object collection keys

Tags: node.js, arangodb, arangojs

Need some help with ArangoDB join query. I have documents like the following, where User contains Group collection keys in nested object`(groups)`. When I query users, I need to join the group collection and alter response. Should be done `WITH QUERY` only. Please check the example give below to get more clarity.

```
// User Collection
[
  {
    _key: "312121"
    name: "Ash",
    groups: {
      "1": ["323223", ...etc], // Group collection _keys;
      "2": ["342323", ...etc] // Group collection _keys;
    } 
  }
]

// Group Collection
[
  {
    _key: "323223"
    name: "Group 1"
  },
  {
    _key: "313131"
    name: "Group 2"
  }
]
```

I tried this query:

```
LET user = DOCUMENT('users/312121')
LET groups_keys = ATTRIBUTES(user.groups) // ["1", "2"]
LET list = (
  FOR key IN groups_keys
  LET groups = (
     FOR group_key IN user.groups[key] // user.groups["1"] and so on..
     LET group = DOCUMENT(CONCAT('groups/', group_key))
     RETURN { group_id: group._key, name: group.name }
  )
  RETURN { [key]: groups }
)

RETURN MERGE(user, { groups: groups })
```

Which returns the `groups` as `Array` but need the `groups` to be an `Object`

```
// Current Output: 
{
  _key: "312121"
  name: "Ash",
  groups: [ // <-- This should be object, not an array
    {
      "1": [{ _key: "323223", name: "Group 1" }]
    },
    {
      "2": [{ _key: "313131", name: "Group 2" }]
    }
  ]
}
```

But It should be in this format:

```
// Expected Output:

{
  _key: "312121"
  name: "Ash",
  groups: { // <-- like this
    "1": [{ _key: "323223", name: "Group 1" }],
    "2": [{ _key: "313131", name: "Group 2" }]
  }
}
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `MERGE`

`MERGE` [[docs](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#merge)] accepts an array parameter as well:

```
LET list = MERGE(
  /* omitted */
  RETURN { [key]: groups }
)
```

#### Using `ZIP`

Alternative solution could also be with `ZIP` [[docs](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#zip)]:

```
LET list = (
  /* omitted */
  RETURN { key, groups } // Notice the format
)
LET obj = ZIP(list[*].key, list[*].groups)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think I've already tried MERGE and ZIp,Will try one more time and let you know.

Comment: `ZIP` worked for me. Thanks Bruh!!, I did try but was missed the `RETURN { key, groups}`.  Anyway Thanks much!!

Comment: @Naren I am glad you managed to make it work! I will update the answer to emphasize that part of the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

try this hope this will help you

```js
const newObject = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(grouped)) { 
  newObject[value[0].<your choice of key or>] = value
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, But This should be with QUERY only. Otherwise, we can use `Array.reduce`